# C transmission as a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-value, function-calls

I am new to C. Can someone explain me whats the difference between these?

I usually use pointers like this:

```
int myFunction(int* something) {
  ...
}

int main() {
  int something;
  something = 0;

  myFunction(&something);
  ...
}
```

But I've found code which looks like this:

```
int myFunction(int& something) {
  ...
}

int main() {
  int something;
  something = 0;

  myFunction(something);
  ...
}
```

It seems like the exactly same thing for me. Is there any difference?

Comment: The earlier marked q is in C++ and this is tagged C. I still believe, they are different languages.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I'm pretty sure you're right:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned, `int myFunction(int& something) {` is ***not*** valid C. It's a reference, which is used in `C++`.

C and C++ **are** different languages, despite the similarity in syntax.

In case, you want to modify the content of `something`, you need to pass a pointer to it to the called function and operate on the pointer. The pointer itself will be passed by value, but by derefrencing the pointer inside the called function, you can achieve the result of pass by reference.

So your first snippet is valid. You should use that in C.

Comment: I see, that's the problem! So I can't use this in C? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

- The former is a pointer, which is valid C.
- The latter is a C++ reference, which is not valid C.

The most notable difference is "syntactic sugar". To access the contents of the pointer `something`, you'll have to type `*something`. When doing the same to the C++ reference `something`, you don't need the `*`.

A more subtle difference is that a pointer can be used for pointer arithmetic. For example, to implement the library function `strlen`, you could do something like this:

```
size_t strlen (const char* s) 
{
  const char* start = s;

  while(*s != '\0')
  {
    s++;
  }

  return (size_t)(s - start);
}
```

This wouldn't be possible if `s` was a reference. You'd have to use separate counters etc.

Note that **a C++ reference is 100% functionally equivalent to a read-only pointer**:

```
int* const something // C equivalent of a reference
```